# Create an interactive 3D plot with a reticular surface using the R RGL library

Tags: r, plot, 3d, surface, rgl

I created a 3D plot with the RGL library for R. The result is this image:

[[image: image with a continuous surface]]

But I need a reticular surface, like this:

[[image: image with reticular surface]]

...preserving the ability of RGL to interactively rotate the plot. How can I do it?

My code is this:

> library(rgl)
>
> bg3d("white")
>
> persp3d(
>     x, y, hdif, col = "lightblue", 
>     xlab = "Years from diagnosis", ylab = "Age at diagnosis", zlab = "Hazard difference",
>     zlim= c(-10, 80), resfac = c(.15, 1), nticks = 70)
>
> grid3d(c("x", "y+", "z"))

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll get something like that if you plot the surface several times with different options.

The first time should be

```
persp3d( x, y, hdif, col = "white", xlab = "Years from diagnosis", 
         ylab = "Age at diagnosis", zlab = "Hazard difference", 
         zlim= c(-10, 80), lit = FALSE)
```

(I left out a couple of your parameters that should not be here:  `nticks` and `resfac`.)  This will get a solid surface, but it won't show up because it is pure white.

The second time should be

```
surface3d( x, y, hdif, col = "blue", front = "lines", back = "cull", lit = FALSE)
```

This will get the blue line mesh.  Finally you can plot

```
surface3d( x, y, hdif, col = "red", front = "cull", back = "lines", lit = FALSE)
```

for the red lines on the back:  but due to rounding error, it might leak
through in some places, so I'd use the same colour for front and back,
i.e.

```
surface3d( x, y, hdif, col = "blue", front = "cull", back = "lines", lit = FALSE)
```

There are likely to be a few artifacts due to rounding; you could add `depth_test = "lequal"` to the mesh calls and it might help, or shift
the front up a tiny bit and the back down a tiny bit by modifying `hdif`.